# Pointer to Direct3D function

Tags: c++, detours

I have code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <detours.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3dx11.h>
#include <d3dcompiler.h>
#include <xnamath.h>
#include <sstream>

#pragma comment(lib, "detours.lib")
BOOL (WINAPI * TrueSetWindowText)(HWND hWnd, LPCTSTR  lpString) = SetWindowText;
```

TrueSetWindowText a pointer to the winapi function SetWindowText. Next I use it all works fine.

I decided to experiment with Direct3D functions. Add:

```
HRESULT (WINAPI * TrueD3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile)(
    ID3D11Device *pDevice, 
    LPCTSTR pSrcFile, 
    D3DX11_IMAGE_LOAD_INFO *pLoadInfo, 
    ID3DX11ThreadPump *pPump, 
    ID3D11ShaderResourceView **ppShaderResourceView,
    HRESULT *pHResult) = D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile;
```

Pointer to [D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). When I compile the project I get an error.

```
dllmain.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFileW@24
fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

In the project properties, VC + + Directories, I added:

Include Dirs C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Microsoft DirectX SDK %28June 2010%29\Include

Lib Dirs C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Microsoft DirectX SDK %28June 2010%29\Lib\x86

Does anyone have any idea why this error appears?

Comment: Silly question but did you set your headers correctly ? Also are you compiling in 32 or 64bits ? Also are you sure of your pointer declaration ?

Comment: I'm not sure what. I have code with my 3d scene. In this code I using function D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile (with same #include include_dir, include_libx86)). All works fine. I try hook my D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile. I use 64bits OS but compile 32. I almost never programmed in C + +, so I think I have a stupid mistake in the syntax.